# Как запомнить значение переменной при переходе на другую страницу

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив массивов, который содержит веб страницы. При нажатии на стрелку вверх клавиатуры, должен осуществляться переход на следующую страницу, при нажатии на стрелку вниз- на предыдущую, стрелки влево и вправо также используются для навигации по массиву ссылок.
Для перехода используется переменные, которые по нажатию на стрелки увеличиваются и соответственно уменьшаются на 1.
Проблема в том, что при загрузке страниц, переменные снова возвращаются в исходное состояние.
Как можно поступить?

```js
let table = [
  ['fi','//localhost:3000/page1.html','se'],
  [5,'//localhost:3000/page2.html',7],
  ['apple','//localhost:3000/page3.html','ssscs'],
  ['for','//localhost:3000/page4.html','dah'],
];

let keyMover = function(i, j) {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    const keyName = event.key;

    if (keyName === "ArrowDown") {
      i--
      if (i < 0) {
        i = 3;
      }
      localStorage.setItem("index", i)

      indexStorage();
    } else if (keyName === "ArrowUp") {
      i++
      if (i > 3) {
        i = 0;
      }
      localStorage.setItem("index", i)

      indexStorage();
    }
  })
};

indexStorage = function() {
  let number = localStorage.getItem("index")

  let currentIndex = table[number][1]

  document.location.href = currentIndex;
}

keyMover(1, 1);
```

Comment: Использовать localStorage или cookie, например.

Answer (score 1):

Храните текущее состояние в `sessionStorage` или `localStorage`